# ResourcelessTransactionManager could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to schedule a Spring Batch on top of Spring boot Application. The following are my configurations. However, i see an error when application start up fails with the following error.

Parameter 0 of method mapJobRepositoryFactory in ScheduleConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager' that could not be found. Can some one throw light on why this is occuring?

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduleConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(
            ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {

        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new
                MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager);

        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(
            MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return launcher;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add @EnableBatchProcessing on top of the class :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(....

Cause...
It conflicts with "PlatformTransactionManager" in "DefaultBatchConfigurer".